# Phonegap setting wallpaper from www assets? Android

Tags: android, cordova, wallpaper

I'm building a phonegap app for Android and need a way to set wallpapers from a .jpg included in the www directory of the app using javascript. How would I go about building a phonegap plugin that works with resources in my phonegap apps www folder?

Comment: You'll have to copy whatever resources you want to use out of the assets folder to the SDCard, as the assets in an app are not accessible when the app is not running.

Answer (score 0):

just read file from asset folder. with Plugin

```
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
    import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
    import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult.Status;
    import org.json.JSONArray;

    import android.app.WallpaperManager;
    import android.content.Context;

    public class testPlugin extends Plugin {
        public final String ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER = "setWallPaper";
        @Override
        public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray arg1, String callbackId) {
            PluginResult result = new PluginResult(Status.INVALID_ACTION);
            if (action.equals(ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER)) {
                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance((Context) this.ctx);
                try {
                  InputStream bitmap=null;
                   bitmap=getAssets().open("www/img/" + arg1.getString(0));//reference to image folder
                    Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bit);
                    result = new PluginResult(Status.OK);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    result = new PluginResult(Status.ERROR, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

this is javascript file test.js

```
var TestPlugin = function () {};

TestPlugin.prototype.set = function (ms, successCallback, failureCallback) {  
//  navigator.notification.alert("OMG");
    return cordova.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'testPlugin', "setWallPaper", [ms]);
};

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin("test", new TestPlugin());
})
```

and main file call Plugin with imagefilename

```
window.plugins.test.set("imageFileName.jpg",
        function () { 
            navigator.notification.alert("Set Success");    
        },
        function (e) {
            navigator.notification.alert("Set Fail: " + e);
        }
    );

;
```

with android device permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

and plugin.xml

```
<plugin name="testPlugin" value="com.android.test.testPlugin"/>
```