# Setting wallpaper from Google Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome-app

How I can set wallpaper for Android from Google Chrome App?
Like this [Phonegap setting wallpaper from www assets? Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598359/phonegap-setting-wallpaper-from-www-assets-android) but without PhoneGap.