# How to set an image as wallpaper in an ionic app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have an image gallery application build using ionic, I need the user to be able to set current image as Home screen wallpaper or Lock screen wallpaper or both. How could I achieve this using **ionic**? Is there a ng-cordova plugin available to set wallpaper?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems like this [Phonegap setting wallpaper from www assets? Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598359/phonegap-setting-wallpaper-from-www-assets-android)

There has a plugin for android set wallpaper, but seems long time no maintain it.
https://github.com/PurpleMADcanada/Wallpaper-PhoneGap-Plugin

ios can't do this, because the sandbox mechanism [Programmatically update background wallpaper of iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642587/programmatically-update-background-wallpaper-of-ios-7)